# Ubuntu 22.10 booting issue

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel, 22.10

Yesterday, I upgraded my Ubuntu to 22.10. However, after installing Ubuntu and restarting the following message is shown:

```
error: shim_lock protocol not found.
error: you need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue ..._
```

How may I resolve the issue?

Comment: What did you upgrade from?

Comment: @Pilot6 from Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: How did you do that? There is no upgrade path from 20.04 to 22.10.

Comment: What were the exact steps or commands you used to upgrade?

Comment: I just used my bootable USB to upgrade to 22.10

Comment: On a dual boot machine with windows 10 and ubuntu 22.04 I just turned the device off and on again ...

Answer (score 0):

On bios, disable fast boot and set operating system to "other" instead of "windoze".